# Harmonic extension for harmonic function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Studying the mean spherical mean and the volumetric mean, this question has occurred to me.

The volumetric mean is defined as follows:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is harmonical.
>
> If $\overline{B(x_0,r)} \subset \Omega$ then
> \begin{equation}
> f(x_0)=\frac{1}{|B(x_0,r)|}\int\limits_{B(x_0,r)}f(x)dx
> \end{equation}

My question is: can we extend $f$ such that we only need $\overline{B(x_0,r)} \subset \overline{\Omega}$ to use the volumetric mean?

This occurred to me when I realized $\overline{B(x_0,r)} \not\subset \Omega$, which violates the condition for the volumetric mean, shown above.

Comment: If $\overline{B(x_0,r)}$ is not contained in $\Omega$, the integral $\int_{B(x_0,r)} f(x)\,{\rm d}x$ may not converge. That is, there are harmonic functions $g\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ that can't be extended to $\overline{\Omega}$.